# Pass Inbound call between twilio clients

Tags: twilio

i have several twilio client users

Sky - Kevin - Paul

A twilio registered number connects to callsky.xml by default / that code looking like.

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Agent>sky</Agent>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

a call comes in and goes to sky, she then wants to pass that call over to Kevin or Paul.

how is this possible ?

tried:

```
$caid = $_REQUEST["CallSID"];

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$call = $client->account->calls->get($caid);
$url = 'http://thesite.com/twiml.xml';

$call->update( 
        'Url' => $url, 
        'Method' => "GET",  
);
```

This is executed through Ajax, when sky presses a button with the destination users name on it.

```
<button onclick="divert('kevin')">Kevin</button>
```

Also: Oddly, the update command shows as a syntax error in my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The update method takes an array, so that might be causing the syntax error:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

I'd also recommened checking out the AppMonitor (https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor) to see if Twilio is logging and errors when trying to retreive the TwiML from your URL.

The URL you point the call at can return static XML, or you ca ndynamically generate it using the PHP helper library.  Here is an example of using the `<Dial>` verb to dial a Client instance:

```
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
$dial = $response->dial(NULL, array(
  'callerId' => '+14152223333'
));
$dial->client('client-id');
print $response;
```

This will output TwiML that looks like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="+14152223333">
    <Client>client-id</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The code I used is taken directly from twilio API docs: must need correcting :(

Comment: Can you point me to which docs you're using?  I'll make sure we get them fixed.

Comment: Also, can i just do something like : $call->update(array(
        'To' => $agentName  
));

Comment: Unfortunately no.  You have to update the calls URL to point to a TwiML document that tells Twilio to <Dial> the $agentName.

Comment: Can I add additional variables at this time - like the name of the client to call. Basically, how do I point to a file which has the right code ? Do I create a divert code for each user ? Can it be dynamic code ?

Comment: The URL can be anything from a static XML file to dynamically generated using whatever your favorite language and web framework are.  I updated my asnwer to reflect this.